# dplyr reordering rows by string

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)


d1 <- data_frame(Nat = c("UK", "UK", "UK", "NONUK", "NONUK", "NONUK"),
 Type = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"))
```

I would like to rearrange the rows so the dataframe looks like this:

```
d2 <- data_frame(
 Nat = c("UK", "UK", "UK", "NONUK", "NONUK", "NONUK"),
 Type = c("b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a"))
```

So the UK and Non UK grouping remains, but the 'Type' rows have shifted. This questions is quite like this one: [Reorder rows conditional on a string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035379/reorder-rows-conditional-on-a-string-variable)

However the answer above is dependent on the rows you are reordering being in alphabetical order (excluding London). Is there a way to reorder a string value more specifically where you select order of the rows yourself, rather than relying on it being alphabetical? Is there a way to do this using dplyr?

Thanks!

Comment: Read about `?factor`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `match`

```
string_order <- c("b", "c", "a")
d1 %>% 
  group_by(Nat) %>% 
  mutate(Type = Type[match(string_order, Type)]) %>%
  ungroup()
#  A tibble: 6 x 2
#  Nat   Type 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 UK    b    
#2 UK    c    
#3 UK    a    
#4 NONUK b    
#5 NONUK c    
#6 NONUK a
```

Comment: thanks for this. What if I add another variable to d1: `number (c(1,2,3,4,5,6))`? How do I make sure that this variable follows the order that I have specified. Hope that makes sense. I can edit the question (or write a new one if that's best practice) if it doesn't make sense

Comment: Do you mean that the order of column `Type` should change while the column `number` remains `c(1,2,3,4,5,6)`? Then the above code should work. If not it might be better to ask a new question with example data and expected output. Best

Comment: No I would like the `number` variable to rearrange to match the order of `Type`. So it would become `2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 4`

Comment: My guess is that you would need columns `Nat` and `Type` to be factors for which you will need to specify the levels as in s_t's answer. Make this a new question and we'll see if there is a more generic dplyr way.

Comment: okay asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52629380/r-dplyr-reorder-rows-by-string

Answer (score 2):

What about explicit the levels in a `dplyr` chain, to choose your order:

```
library(dplyr)
d1 %>%
arrange(factor(.$Nat, levels = c("UK", "NONUK")), factor(.$Type, levels = c("c", "b","a")))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Nat   Type 
  <chr> <chr>
1 UK    c    
2 UK    b    
3 UK    a    
4 NONUK c    
5 NONUK b    
6 NONUK a
```

Another example:

```
d1 %>%
arrange(factor(.$Nat, levels = c("UK", "NONUK")), factor(.$Type, levels = c("b", "c","a")))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  Nat   Type 
  <chr> <chr>
1 UK    b    
2 UK    c    
3 UK    a    
4 NONUK b    
5 NONUK c    
6 NONUK a
```